# Swashbuckle <summary> alternative

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

Lets say I have the following Method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Just a Method
/// </summary>
[HttpGet()]
[Produces("plain/text")]
public IActionResult Foo() => this.Ok("Some Data..");
```

Swagger is showing me the following:
[image]

Can I achieve the same result, without using `<summary>` ? Is there an attribute or something I could use?

Iam asking because if I run my project on my machine everything works fine, but if i run it on another it doesnt show the description "Just a Method".
It seems like the XML comments get ignored..

I can't post a single peace of the code so please just tell me if theres a work around so i dont have to use `<summary>`.

Thanks!

Comment: XML comments are the standard way to document methods, if it's not showing on another machine, then it's that machine that is at fault.

Comment: Are you correctly deploying your application? Swagger uses the compiled xml docs and they need to be deployed (and/or build if you just run as project) on the target system too

Comment: Can you add more info regarding how you are running it on another machine?

Comment: @Tseng this question is pretty old, but you were correct. I forgot to reply here. The xml file was not deployed, therefore the documentation did not work.